# Создание копии существующего списка

Tags: java, массивы

Добрый день. Имеется заполненный ArrayList (например list1). Как создать новый ArrayList (list2), который будет копией list1, но отсортированным?

Comment: Покажите конкретный код, где у вас не получилось что-либо сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeSet` уберёт все дупликаты и отсортирует ваш исходный список.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("three");
list.add("three");
list.add("two");
list.add("one");

TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(list);

System.out.println(list); // [three, three, two, one]
System.out.println(set);  // [one, three, two]
```

Или так (без потери дупликатов):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("three");
list.add("two");
list.add("one");

ArrayList<String> copyOfList = new ArrayList<>(list); 
copyOfList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());           

System.out.println(list);       // [three, three, two, one]
System.out.println(copyOfList); // [one, three, three, two]
```

Comment: но как быть если нужно учитывать повторные элементы?)

Comment: @Санаев дополнил ответ.

Comment: Второй вариант подходит, но как быть, если надо отсортировать по длине каждого элемента?

Comment: @moffire в этом случае необходимо писать свой компаратор

Comment: @Санаев понял, спасибо.